# How to Re-runs the setup() function on arduino from c#? (restart arduino)

Tags: installation, arduino

Pressing on serial monitor on arduino editor Re-runs the setup() function. How to Re-runs the setup() function from c#?
I build software with c# that communicates with Arduino but when I run the software arduino has already started work because is USB connected. How can I reboot the arduino board from c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset by calling `asm volatile ("  jmp 0");` into your `C` code.